# How to allow multiple DateTime format in moment object

Tags: javascript, node.js, datetime, utc

I have the next attribute:

```
lastUpdated: moment.utc().format('YYYY-MM-DDTHH:mm:ssZ')
```

this attribute has a preset format but is just one. I need to allow that attribute to use more than one format, I want the attribute to have multiple formats, depending on the input. More exactly I want to have the following formats able on my attribute: YYYY, YYYY-MM, YYYY-MM-DD or YYYY-MM-DDThh:mm:ss+zz:zz, but at the same time, depending on the input.

how can I do that?

Comment: Just so I understand correctly, you want `lastUpdated` to hold multiple values, like so - `lastUpdated: [moment.utc().format(...), moment.utc().format(...), ...]`?

Comment: more or less... I want to be able to introduce the value 2020 or 2020-02 or 2020-02-05, but the lastUpdated attribute to be a Date, not an array of dates

Comment: So why not store it as date, and then whenever you need to use `lastUpdated` you can just take the date object and format it however you want it?

Comment: Because I want to allow just these formats, not any format

Comment: So essentially you're asking, "how to store multiple values in the `lastUpdated` property without using an array or an object"? If that's the case, that's not possible.

Comment: I want to store one value... and this value I want to be stored in different formats... depending on cases

Comment: Different formats would imply different values, hence multiple values.

Comment: hmmm.... thx :)